# Insert 3000 rows into Room Database but Method too large

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, persistence, android-room

I'm trying to prepopulate a database, I generated the insert data but
when I run the app it gives this build error:

```
Caused by: org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.MethodTooLargeException: Method too large:
```

I have a funtion like this:

```
RoomDatabase.Callback(){

    override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
        super.onCreate(db)
        
        val pDao = database.get().pDao()
        val pLangDao = database.get().pLangDao()

        applicationScope.launch {
            
            insertPWithPLangEnglish_1_10(pDao, pLangDao)
           
        }

    }
}


private suspend fun insertPWithPLangEnglish_1_10(pDao: PDao, pLangDao: PLangDao){
    var insId = pDao.insert(P(pcId = 1))
    pLangDao.insert(PLang(pItemId = insId.toInt(), title = "herbert", locale = "en_US", langCode = "en"))
    insId = pDao.insert(P(pcId = 1))
    pLangDao.insert(PLang(pItemId = insId.toInt(), title = "others", locale = "en_US", langCode = "en"))
    
    ... and so on about 3000 more lines
}
```

Any idea how to solve this?

P class is the following:

```
@Entity(tableName = "p")
@Parcelize
data class P (
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "pid")
    val pId: Int = 0,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "pc_id")
    val pcId: Int,
    val created: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()

) : Parcelable {
}
```

PLang class is the following:

```
@Entity(tableName = "p_lang")
@Parcelize
data class PLang (
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "p_lang_id")
    val pLangId: Int = 0,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "p_item_id")
    val pItemId: Int,
    val locale: String = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "lang_code")
    val langCode: String,
    val title: String,
    val description: String = ""

) : Parcelable {

}
```

Now I'm trying another way with help of Workers, and seed database from json files.

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/prepopulate

Comment: Can you post your P and PLang classes? How are they related?

Comment: thanks @Michael I found another way, seeding database from json files with help of Workers. A bit tricky and can't get working at the moment but I hope this will be the way to do this

Comment: @luca_999 I posted the classes

Answer (score 0):

So clearly, the Kotlin compiler is complaining because your method is too long and you should optimize it.

In order to do that you could create a global list containing all your `PLang` objects:

```
val pLangList = listOf(
    PLang(title = "herbert", locale = "en_US", langCode = "en"),
    PLang(title = "others", locale = "en_US", langCode = "en"),
    ...
)
```

Note that I didn't set the `pItemId` property, in fact, you should also change your `PLang` class, assigning a default value to it for convenience:

```
@Entity(tableName = "p_lang")
@Parcelize
data class PLang (
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "p_lang_id")
    val pLangId: Int = 0,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "p_item_id")
    val pItemId: Int = -1,              // <--- Added default value here
    val locale: String = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "lang_code")
    val langCode: String,
    val title: String,
    val description: String = ""

) : Parcelable {

}
```

Now you can loop through your list and add every item with just 3 lines of code instead of ~3000:

```
private suspend fun insertPWithPLangEnglish_1_10(pDao: PDao, pLangDao: PLangDao)
{
    for (pLang in pLangList) 
    {
        val insId = pDao.insert(P(pcId = 1))
        pLangDao.insert(PLang(pItemId = insId.toInt(), title = pLang.title, locale = pLang.locale, langCode = pLang.langCode))
    }
}
```